# Vertically align two items by the middle of each item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Sorry if the title is confusing. Hopefully, the image speaks for itself.

How can I use css to align the middle of the plus sign with the cross section of the x?

I know I could use something like position to nudge the x up a few pixels but I'm looking for a more consistent solution that works for several different screen sizes.

Heres the HTML. `pretty-link` is just a class with the cursor property set to hand and pointer

```
<span className='pull-right' style={{verticalAlign: 'middle', margin: 'auto', display: 'inline-block'}}>
    <i className='fa fa-minus pretty-link' style={{verticalAlign: 'middle'}} onClick={e => toggleSystemUnit(e, index)}></i>
    <i className='fa fa-times pretty-link' style={{verticalAlign: 'middle'}}></i>
</span>
```

Here is an example utilizing flex, does not work

http://jsfiddle.net/f1aejwwf/1/

Here is an example utilizing vertical-align, does not work

http://jsfiddle.net/hw4au2km/

In each example the x remains slightly below the +

Setting explicit widths for a wrapping span and floating each:

http://jsfiddle.net/u99q01t2/2/

In each of these examples the x seems to land slightly below the + so maybe it's a problem with fa?

For anyone coming here from Google, I do not think the fa-times icon can easily be aligned this way. All the above solutions work great for fa-plus and fa-minus but the fa-times icon is slightly off-center. Maybe someone can find a solution to that but for now I've switched to material icons for my project.

Comment: share your code or fiddle

Comment: @DarrenSweeney you can see in my code that I have definitely made multiple attempts to solve this problem. The code posted in response to me (display: flex) has already been tried and also did not work. It's fine if you're too busy to help but I don't see how you can say I made no attempt. I wouldn't come here and ask a question if I hadn't tried to solve this on my own

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak You added the code after I added my comment, or at least very close timing...it wasn't there when you first asked the question.

Comment: @hungerstar I fail to see how it is appropriate to say I made no attempt or call me "sensitive". I included code. I edited my response to include more code thanks to your comment. If you need more I am happy to provide it

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak it's still not [a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All you need to do is provide the generated markup and any other resources like CSS and Font Awesome. No need for the React stuff. Those that have posted answers have provided an example of what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

Comment: @hungerstar now I have tons of examples. care to take a crack at this? there is an implementation of each answer on jsfiddle but none of them work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two images are horizontally aligned on the baseline, that's why you need to add some `margin-bottom` to the right one in order to make them horizontally centered, I think `2px` do the job just fine:

```css
.pretty-link {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* display: inline-block; not necessary */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.containerdiv {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline */
  justify-content: space-between; /* children are evenly distributed, first child is on the far left, last on the far right */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment / centering */
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='containerdiv'>
  <h4>Detail</h4>
  <span class='pull-right'>
    <i class='fa fa-plus pretty-link'></i>
    <i class='fa fa-times pretty-link' style="margin-bottom: 2px;"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't this bad practice though? I'm obviously not great at css or design but wouldn't this display differently on different screen sizes?

Comment: Not in this case. Inline-styling is a bad practice but you can change that easily. It shouldn't and it won't cause any trouble no matter the screen size or the `.containerdiv` height.

Answer (score 1):

I created this snippet to help you with your question. As you can see the two blocks have different heights but giving them `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;` they are vertically centered. Hope it helps :)

```css
.element.first {
  font-size: 65px;
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.element.second {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: yellow;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element first">First Icon</div>
  <div class="element second">Second Icon</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f1aejwwf/1/ I put the code in a fiddle and applied those properties but it still isn't quite right

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flexbox or line-height](https://jsfiddle.net/javierfdezgomez/68av5t05/3/) . Flexbox is the greatest way if you are using [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and a task runner.

**HTML**

```
<h3>
Normal
</h3>
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-minus pretty-link"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times  pretty-link"></i>
    Lorem ipsum
</span>
<hr>
<h3>
Flex
</h3>
<span class="container-flex">
    <i class="fa fa-minus pretty-link"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times  pretty-link"></i>
    Lorem ipsum
</span>
<hr>
<h3>
Line Height
</h3>
<span class="container-line-height">
    <i class="fa fa-minus pretty-link"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times  pretty-link"></i>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-flex{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;  
}

.container-line-height .fa{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `span` class a width and height, then give your first `<i>` class `float:left;`  and your second `<i>`class`float:right;` Both `<i>`must have width in px;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .textpart {
      margin-left: -6px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1 class="text">+<span class="textpart">X</span></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: same results as all the others, I think the issue is with the fa icons themselves. thanks for your help